# HTML tag showing in bottom on ckeditor

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 3.2 and I am facing the problem to hide the HTML tag which is showing in bottom on CKEditor. Is anybody have done this type of customization please share with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the [FAQ about CKEditor](http://cksource.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=17301)

```
config.removePlugins = 'elementspath';
```